# Can not connect to remote server

Tags: web-services

While using an external user service, the following error occurs.

> Unable to connect to the remote server

Can anyone can explain what is going wrong? An elaborate explanation regarding using an external web service would helpful.

Here is some of my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace sample_app
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
            byte[] abc = proxy.DownloadData((new Uri("http://www.webservicex.net/WS/CATs.aspx?CATID=12&DESC=Utilities")));
            Stream strm = new MemoryStream(abc);
```

Comment: Did you change the URL for an actual real URL in your code?

Comment: hi Filip! url is same as per code.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought that was just an example URL, now I see it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Try `byte[] abc = proxy.DownloadData("http://www.webservicex.net/WS/CATs.aspx?CATID=12&DESC=Utilities");`

`WebClient.DownloadData` method should take a string as a paremeter, so maybe it's just not interpreting the Uri class well?

Comment: Hi!!!!! Thanks a lot Deanna for editing the question.           Dear Filip I tried the code with removing all the line but intial two (that is by removing line for Stream) still its not working

Comment: Then I don't know what could be wrong, the code looks fine to me. Are you sure your firewall does not block the connection?